# Bulk upload weight to products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-weight, bulk-products-update

Is it possible to bulk upload 'weight' to existing products in Magento 2?

I have a list of 1200 products on Magneto which are live on my site but would like to bulk add their individual weight without going through and doing this manually.

Is this possible? We are currently using Magento Version 2.3.5.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could [export](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/data-export.html) your products as CSV, update the weight in the file then importing it back using the import feature with *'add/update'* operation. Please check the [official import documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/data-import.html) and try this first on a testing environment.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are most welcome :)